# reduce() return value can't show in the HTML in react by using map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My output is
[image]

By writing this code below

```js
var allblogs = [{
    "banner": "41173047269_1594284317134_88820381534.png",
    "approved_status": 1,
    "posted_month": "July",
    "posted_year": "2020",
    "_id": "5f06d9270d63372f7409fe2b",
    "title": "Blog 05 Admin",
    "posted_by": "5eeb50cb9d71910990c6380a",
    "createdAt": "2020-07-09T08:45:27.688Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-09T08:45:27.688Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "banner": "63627386743_1594284270142_61158225624.png",
    "photo": "93402529321_1594284276419_88266235152.png",
    "posted_month": "June",
    "posted_year": "2020",
    "_id": "5f06d8fb0d63372f7409fe2a",
    "title": "Blog 04 Admin ",
    "author": "asif",
    "published_Date": "2020-07-22T18:00:00.000Z",
    "posted_by": "5eeb50cb9d71910990c6380a",
    "createdAt": "2020-07-09T08:44:43.901Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-09T08:44:43.901Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
]

let archives = []
archives = allblogs.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a.posted_month + ' ' + a.posted_year] = [...r[a.posted_month + ' ' + a.posted_year] || [], a]
  return r;
}, []);

console.log(typeof(archives));
console.log(archives);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I want to show this value in HTML in react. I use map function but it doesn't work. but I don't understand why this array not work.

Comment: Could you please add reactjs code also to the question?

Comment: Why doesn't `array::map` work for you? Is there an error? What isn't working? Please provide more and better details, a working code snippet, and what your expected result should be.

Answer (score 0):

Your `reduce` will return `object` not `array`. To get `array` follow these steps.

In your `reduce` you need to change result to `{}` instead of `[]`. So it will return `object` with `key` as your month i.e. `June 2020` and `value` as `[]`.

Then you can use `Object.entries(archives)` which will give you array like `[key, value]` for each `property`. Then use `.map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));` to get your desired `array` result.

Test it below.

```js
var allblogs = [{
    "banner": "41173047269_1594284317134_88820381534.png",
    "approved_status": 1,
    "posted_month": "July",
    "posted_year": "2020",
    "_id": "5f06d9270d63372f7409fe2b",
    "title": "Blog 05 Admin",
    "posted_by": "5eeb50cb9d71910990c6380a",
    "createdAt": "2020-07-09T08:45:27.688Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-09T08:45:27.688Z",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "banner": "63627386743_1594284270142_61158225624.png",
    "photo": "93402529321_1594284276419_88266235152.png",
    "posted_month": "June",
    "posted_year": "2020",
    "_id": "5f06d8fb0d63372f7409fe2a",
    "title": "Blog 04 Admin ",
    "author": "asif",
    "published_Date": "2020-07-22T18:00:00.000Z",
    "posted_by": "5eeb50cb9d71910990c6380a",
    "createdAt": "2020-07-09T08:44:43.901Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-07-09T08:44:43.901Z",
    "__v": 0
  }
];

let archives = []
archives = allblogs.reduce((r, a) => {
  r[a.posted_month + ' ' + a.posted_year] = [...r[a.posted_month + ' ' + a.posted_year] || [], a]
  return r;
}, {}); // <-- change [] to {}.

let arrayArchives = Object.entries(archives).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));

console.log(arrayArchives);
```